# Update a JSON field with eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How can I update a JSON field with eloquent? The field casts to an array.

I cannot use `update` as I cannot make the field mass assignable.

I cannot to `$myModel->myField = ["some" => "value"]` as it will erase any other json data on the field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `forceFill()` like this:

```
$myModel->forceFill(['myField->some' => 'value'])->save();
```

Comment: This is not the correct answer as this ignores all other fillable rules you might have and bring issues. Just make sure you define the `myField` in the fillable together with any subproperties seperated with a ->. So: 'myField', 'myField->some`.